# How to set default Cell Setup to all type of cells?

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I'd like to setup my form cells background color

It's possible to set for a type of row (aka RowType)

```
CheckRow.defaultCellSetup = { cell, row in cell.backgroundColor = .orangeColor() }
```

but is it possible to set it once for any type (globally) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the appearance proxy to customize the properties of a type globally from the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.

```
CheckRow.appearance()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way of doing this and one way may be better than other, it will depend on how many cells or row types you need to change. I know two ways (Swift 4)

The first one, a variation of Ahmed Onawale answer. Inside `viewDidLoad()`, setup the cell for each row type you want to globally configure.

```
IntRow.defaultCellSetup = { cell, row in
     cell.backgroundColor = .orange
}
```

This will work, although it may become tedious if every cell of each row type shares the same functionality, if that's the case, one will have to setup each cell of every Row type, one by one, like so:

```
IntRow.defaultCellSetup  = { cell, row in cell.backgroundColor = .orange }
DateRow.defaultCellSetup = { cell, row in cell.backgroundColor = .orange }
TextRow.defaultCellSetup = { cell, row in cell.backgroundColor = .orange }
```

For the scenario described above there's another way.

For-loop through every cell of the tableView, like so:

```
    for row in form.allRows {
        let cell = row.baseCell

        cell?.backgroundColor = .orange
    }
```

Make sure the code above runs after you setup your form (at the end of viewDidLoad), so your cell's configuration don't get override by Eureka's